# Chrome Extension scripts not firing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've seen a bunch of posts about this question, but none of the solutions seem to have worked for me. I have a simple manifest with a background, popup.html, and popup.js. It looks like the script isn't doing anything (just trying to get an alert). I'm trying to figure out if there's something I'm missing somewhere (and hoping I haven't just made a really stupid mistake).

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "ext",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description":"ext",
    "permissions": ["declarativeContent", "activeTab"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent":false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
        "16": "16_px_icon.ico"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "16_px_icon.ico"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({saves:[]} );
});

chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
    conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
      pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'developer.chrome.com'},
    })
    ],
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
  }]);
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        button {
            height: 30px;
            width: 60px;
            outline:none;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="popup.js" ></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="Fd">
        <button id="Btn">
        Search</button>
        <span id="Msg"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function search() {
    alert('A')
}


window.onload = function() {
    
//document.getElementById('Btn').addEventListener('click', search); tried this

document.getElementById('Btn').onclick = search;

}
```

Comment: Typo: `scr` should `src`. You can find such mistakes by using devtools. The popup is a separate window so it has its own devtools: right-click inside the popup, then click "inspect". For example, in this case you will want to debug popup.js and you'll see it is not listed in Sources panel which means there's a problem with the way it's declared, and there you'll see the typo.

Comment: Sweet, that was it. Thanks for the tip about the devtools - I was looking in the main window, so of course I wasn't seeing any errors at all.